# request Vimeo private video file as Pro account

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

I want request my private video file by using video id(my account is Pro). but I don't have a idea how to credential my account in request.

This is what i did!

`GET https://api.vimeo.com/videos/{video_id}`

body

```
{
  "grant_type": "client_credentials"
}
```

header

```
"Authorization" : "bearer {access_token}"
"Accept" : "application/vnd.vimeo.user+json;version=3.0,application/vnd.vimeo.video+json;version=3.4"
"Content-Type" : "application/json"
```

and this is resposne about that..

```
{
    "error": "Something strange occurred. Please contact the app owners.",
    "link": null,
    "developer_message": "No user credentials were provided.",
    "error_code": 8003
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're generating a `client_credentials` token, which can only retrieve public data on Vimeo. Instead, you need to generate an authenticated token, either via the OAuth workflow or a Personal Access Token on the Vimeo Developer Site. More information here:

https://developer.vimeo.com/api/authentication#using-the-auth-code-grant-step-1
https://developer.vimeo.com/api/guides/start/#generate-access-token

Answer (score 0):

Generate access_token from your account after adding NEW APP.
then pass access_token in the URL or as a parameter
e.g https://api.vimeo.com/videos?access_token=***********************&links=https://vimeo.com/29474908